# Update InstagramID from Instagram Username sql

Tags: sql, asp.net-core, instagram-api

I'm trying to create a sql script (migration script) which will update the instagramID based of the users instagram username.

I've currently got two columns in my Users Table which are InstagramUsername(string and InstagramID(string)

How would I get the username and ID from a URL like so: https://www.instagram.com/therock/?__a=1

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the username (`therock`) like above you can issue a HTTP GET to that constructed URL and read the JSON payload value at `graphql.user.id` and there is your Instagram ID.

Comment: is there any documentation I can follow?

Comment: @rey123 search the web for how to perform HTTP requests and parse JSON responses